AI search tool recommendation
What AI search tools are available as of December 2024 that can handle domain-specific queries, provide additional utilities (such as generating mind maps, creating slides, and supporting user-added sources), and offer fast response times?
Below are some tools I’ve looked into:

You.com
hika.fyi
Felo.ai (can generate mind maps, slides, supports user-added sources)
Perplexity.ai
Brave Search (similar to Bing Copilot)
ChatGPT Web Search
Waldo Search
Komo.ai
AndiSearch.com
Zenfetch.com
Phind.com
Getliner.com (academic specifically?)

Any recommendations or insights would be greatly appreciated!

hi, Aspen.  I would also like to learn more about the various AIs out there. Your question has been closed because it doesn't meet the requirements for an answerable question on this site. 1) Lose the word "best" in the title, as it is subjective and 2) list the features that you seek in an AI 3) say of it needs to be gratis. If you are willing to pay, state a budget. If you do that, the question will quickly be reopened, and I will nbe actively following it :-)

I don't understand what you need. You want domain specific queries (which domain? or Internet domains, like TLDs?) and then create a mind map, or a presentation from that? What does "fast response time" mean, when it comes to create a presentation? How many seconds do you have to prepare for such a presentation? Or do you measure response time in minutes?

If you have already tried those 11 products, why didn't you like each one of them? Which of your requirement did each product not fulfill?
